# Sum currency with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, currency

I'm trying to sum currency in Javascript. I want that the sum be displayed and updated on any changes in the fields. But the most I could get was to present the results via a button.

Here is the code:

```
<script>

function myFunction() {

    var total=0;

    var x = $('.total'); // ; was missing

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        var str = x[i].value; // use .value

        var n = str.replace(",", ".");
        var n1 = n.replace("R$ ", "");

        total += parseFloat(n1);

    }

    sum.value = total.toFixed(2);

    $('#sum').priceFormat({
        prefix: 'R$  ',
        centsSeparator: ',',//a separação de decimais no float é com '.'
        thousandsSeparator: '.',
        centsLimit:2,
        allowNegative: true,
    });

}

</script>
```

total is a class of inputs.

Comment: If you bothered to read through jQuery tutorials and/or searched the documentation, you'd know how to assign a simple event handler. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: `<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>` This is from your other question. So you already know how to assign an event handler using that technique. So what's the problem?

Comment: The heading of the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onkeyup` event. `keyup` in jQuery. You can also use (`on`)`keypress`.